# Could not create proxy factory for org.jboss.security.acl.ACLEntryImpl

Tags: hibernate, classnotfoundexception, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have a war archive which I want to deploy but I get an exception claiming about a missing class (*org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy*).

I don't understand why I get this exception, because the hibernate core is part of the WildFly 8.2.0 Final.

How can I understand and resolve this issue?

```
14:13:57,803 WARN  [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) HHH000305: Could not create proxy factory for:org.jboss.security.acl.ACLEntryImpl: org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: org.jboss.security.acl.ACLEntryImpl
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:166) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:67) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:224) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:212) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor181.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor180.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:515) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:492) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:428) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:400) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:162) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:170) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:507) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass2(FactoryHelper.java:182) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:164) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy from [Module "org.picketbox:main" from local module loader @371eaf4e (finder: local module finder @3f874627 (roots: C:\_apps\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules,C:\_apps\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 45 more

2015-05-26 14:22:13,026 ERROR [org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: org.jboss.security.acl.ACLEntryImpl: java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:515) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:492) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:428) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:400) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:162) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:67) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:224) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:212) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor176.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor168.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:170) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:507) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass2(FactoryHelper.java:182) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:164) [javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:3.18.0-GA]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy from [Module "org.picketbox:main" from local module loader @371eaf4e (finder: local module finder @3f874627 (roots: C:\_apps\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules,C:\_apps\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 45 more
```